# How to bind the xml deatils in html dropdownlist

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

```html
    <Agencies>

  <Deatils>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
  </Deatils>

  <Deatils>

    <Id>2</Id>
    <Name>CDE</Name>
  </Deatils>

</Agencies>
<Consultant>

  <Deatils>
    <Id>10</Id>
    <Name>LMN</Name>

   </Deatils>
  <Deatils>
    <Id>11</Id>
    <Name>OPQ</Name>
  </Deatils>
</Consultant>
```

I want the above Consultant and Agencies details name tag to be bonded in the 2 mvc Dropdownlistfor i,e: ABC, CDE in one dropdown and LMN,OPQ in another dropdown. How will I achieve it

Comment: Read that XML file and prepare c# model with same properties and then fill that model list

Answer (score 0):

Put your XML file inside App_Data or anywhere in program and in MapPath.
Assign their path and also assign the name of your first XML column in the last line.

Here I'm using "code" because it is my first XML column and country is the name of the column I want to show in my dropdownlist.

```
private void BindCountry()
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~//App_Data//countries.xml"));

    foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//country"))
    {
        ddlcountry.Items.Add(new ListItem(node.InnerText, node.Attributes["code"].InnerText));
    }
}
```

Comment: How to get the items from 2 nodes and add to a single model in one foreach loop?                i,e:<Agencies> and  <Consultant> details need to be fetched into single model?